# How can I receive the content from the datarow I am dragging in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

I have used a DatagridDragDropTarget from Silverlight-Toolkit I found at Codeplex. 
When I drag a row in the datagrid I want to get the variable ID from the row. When I drop the row over the target (another datagrid) the function DataGridDragDropTarget_ItemDragCompleted is called.
This function is not working 100 % because I cant figure out the way to print the column ID in the row I dragged. As you can see at the video I posted at  [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bNznwbNzzs/)!

the label prints out

> System.Collection.Objectmode.selection

When I debug. Here is the function:

```
    private void DataGridDragDropTarget_ItemDragCompleted(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Content = "Function is called";
        SelectionCollection secCol = e.Data as SelectionCollection;
        for (int i = 0; i < secCol.Count; i++)
        {
            Label1.Content += " " +  secCol[i].ToString();
        }
    }
```

And here is most important part of the xaml. The full source code can be found at my dropbox:

```
<toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True"
                                        AllowedSourceEffects="Copy"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Margin="10, 10, 0, 0"
                                        ItemDragCompleted="DataGridDragDropTarget_ItemDragCompleted" >
                <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          Height="150"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Name="FirstGrid"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Width="476"
                          ColumnWidth="*"
                          SelectionMode="Extended"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}"
                                            Header="Id" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                            Header="Name" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BookTitle}"
                                            Header="BookTitle" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DOB}"
                                            Header="DOB" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsMVP}"
                                            Header="IsMVP" />
                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                </sdk:DataGrid>
            </toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget>
            <sdk:Label Name="Label1" Height="28" Width="420" Margin="140,0"/>
            <sdk:DataGrid AllowDrop="True" Height="125" Margin="92,0,81,0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YourBindedClass secCol = e.Data as YourBindedClass;
```

//This is the datarow.
You can access the properties then,

```
Label1.Content = secCol.Property1.ToString();
```

Comment: It doesent print out anything...  for (int i = 0; i < secCol.Count; i++)
            {
                List<Author> secCoal = secCol[i].Item as List<Author>;
                Label1.Content += " " + secCoal[i].ID;

            }

Comment: why you are taking as a LIst

Comment: Good Question. I changed to take it as a Observable Collection instead and now it works